# Mouse and screen lock up

Tags: mouse, screen, lockup

I have Ubuntu 14.04.  At first the browser was all chopped up into long rectangles.  And the mouse wouldn't work then the pointer disappeared.
Now the mouse locks up and the pointer disappears and any audio/video that is playing gets scrambled.  I have reloaded 14.04 and am thinking of getting 15.04.  What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but to me it sounds like a memory leak or a fired piece of hardware.

I recommend trying a fresh install and inspecting your hardware for issues or loose cables.